# How do use inheritance in xsd to make multiple elements type of another

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to model Xml such as

```
.......
<mood1>
   <positive>true</positive>
   <probability>23</probability>
</mood1>
<mood2>
   <positive>false</positive>
   <probability>86</probability>
</mood2>
.........
```

in an xml schema, currently I have

```
<xs:element name="mood1">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="category"/>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="mood2">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="category"/>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="category">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

but of course that would model having an additional unneccessary category element such as

```
.......
<mood1>
   <category> 
     <positive>true</positive>
     <probability>23</probability>
   </category> 
</mood1>
<mood2>
  <category>
    <positive>false</positive>
    <probability>86</probability>
  </category>
</mood2>
.........
```

which I dont want.

I could do

```
<xs:element name="mood1">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="mood2">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But then I have to keep on repeating the same definition (and there is more than just mood1 and mood2).

I want to say mood1 is a **subtype** of category but I don't know how to, its worth noting mood1 and mood2 do have identical elements but they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer you define common elements as a complexType and then your top level elements refer to the complexType through the type attribute

i.e

```
<xs:complexType name="category">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="positive" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <xs:element name="probability" type="xs:float"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="mood1" type="category"/>
<xs:element name="mood2" type="category"/>
```